# Считывать нажатия кнопок в WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

В приложении важны доли секунды для точных вычислений. Можно ли после введенного значения в TextBox нажав кнопку Enter выполнялся какой либо блок кода. Ну или условие какое сделать. Выслушаю все предложения

[image: Заде]

Задействовано только кнопка поле ввода и 0 + 0

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int result = 0;
        int num1 = label1.Text.ToInt();
        int num2 = label3.Text.ToInt();
        string operation = label2.Text;
        switch (operation)
        {
            case "+":
                result = num1 + num2;
                break;
            case "-":
                result = num1 - num2;
                break;
            case "/":
                result = num1 / num2;
                break;
            case "*":
                result = num1 * num2;
                break;
        }
        if (result == textBox1.Text.ToInt())
            right++;
        else
            wrong++;
        Random r = new Random();
        label1.Text = r.Next(1, 51).ToString();
        label3.Text = r.Next(1, 51).ToString();
        switch (r.Next(0, 2))
        {
            case 0:
                label2.Text = "+";
                break;
            case 1:
                label2.Text = "-";
                break;
            case 2:
                label2.Text = "*";
                break;
            case 3:
                label2.Text = "/";
                break;
        }
    }
```

Можно ли что бы не нажатие на кнопку выполняло это действие а кнопка Enter

Comment: Потоки рассматривали?

Comment: Не применял никогда да и вообще с этим слабо знаком. Можете в ответ написать ваш вариант. Рано или поздно все равно надо пробовать

Comment: а вы поставьте задачу корректно, возможно вам нужны и не потоки, или вы хотите что-бы я угадывал что вам нужно?

Comment: сейчас секунду.

Comment: Да, было бы неплохо иметь наличие подробностей. Вам нужно, чтобы пока вы работали с программой она что-то считали или просто можно нажать на enter и подождать выполнения?

Comment: Правил вопрос. Думаю так понятно

Comment: а-а-а понял, вам надо по нажатию на кнопку что-бы появилось действие!

Comment: Или что бы нажималась кнопка по нажатию на Enter

Comment: @SeeSharp добавил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можно, в WinForms есть специальные обработчики для таких случаев.
Например, можно у textbox в панели `события` включить обработчик `KeyPress`

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
    {
        textbox1.Text = "вот и обработалось нажатие".
    }
}
```

Тоже самое можно сделать у формы, т.е. добавить обработчик события к форме:

```
public void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
    {
        textbox1.Text = "вот и обработалось нажатие".
    }
}
```

Обработчики событий, например, в VisualStudio можно объявить в коде двойным нажатием на `<название события>` в панели свойств объекта, во вкладке `события`.

Comment: e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter - без приведения не будет работать, так как в первом случае у вас тип char, во втором Keys.

Comment: @VladimirT ошибся, прошу прощения